# How can I use `defineProperty` to create a readonly array property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, native-methods

I have the following as a part of a module (names simplified for purpose of question):

In "module.js":

```
var _arr;

_arr = [];

function ClassName () {
    var props = {};

    // ... other properties ...

    props.arr = {
        enumerable: true,
        get: function () {
            return _arr;
        }
    };

    Object.defineProperties(this, props); 

    Object.seal(this);
};

ClassName.prototype.addArrValue = function addArrValue(value) {

    // ... some code here to validate `value` ...

    _arr.push(value);
}
```

In "otherfile.js":

```
var x = new ClassName();
```

With the implementation above, and the sample code below, adding values to `arr` can be achieved in two ways.

```
// No thank you.
x.arr.push("newValue"); // x.arr = ["newValue"];

// Yes please!
x.addArrValue("newValue"); // Only this route is desired.
```

Does anyone know how to achieve a readonly array property?

*Note: `writeable` is false by default and no difference is observed if I explicitly set it.*

Comment: You aren't writing the property; you're mutating the array that it holds.

Comment: That is true... Perhaps I need to think up a better solution.

Comment: Look at `Object.seal()`

Comment: Object.seal() on props.arr could work, but I don't think I would be able to "unseal" it for when I mutate it in the "x.addArrValue" fn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) will do what you're asking (on browsers properly implementing the spec).  Attempts to modify the array will either fail silently or throw `TypeError` when in strict mode.

The easiest solution is to return a new frozen copy (freeze is destructive):

```
return Object.freeze(_arr.slice());
```

However, if more reading than writing is expected, lazy-cache the most recently accessed frozen copy and purge upon write (since `addArrValue` controls writes)

Lazy caching read-only copy using modified original example:

```
"use strict";
const mutable = [];
let cache;

function ClassName () {
    const props = {};

    // ... other properties ...

    props.arr = {
        enumerable: true,
        get: function () {
            return cache || (cache = Object.freeze(mutable.slice());
        }
    };

    Object.defineProperties(this, props); 

    Object.seal(this);
};

ClassName.prototype.addArrValue = function addArrValue(value) {

    // ... some code here to validate `value` ...

    mutable.push(value);
    cache = undefined;
}
```

Lazy caching read-only copy using ES2015 classes:

```
class ClassName {
    constructor() {
        this.mutable = [];
        this.cache = undefined;
        Object.seal(this);
    }

    get arr() {
        return this.cache || (this.cache = Object.freeze(this.mutable.slice());
    }

    function addArrValue(value) {
        this.mutable.push(value);
        this.cache = undefined;
    }
}
```

A "transparent" re-usable class ***hack*** (rarely required):

```
class ReadOnlyArray extends Array {
    constructor(mutable) {
        // `this` is now a frozen mutable.slice() and NOT a ReadOnlyArray
        return Object.freeze(mutable.slice()); 
    }
}

const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const array2 = new ReadOnlyArray(array1);

console.log(array1); // Array ["a", "b", "c"]
console.log(array2); // Array ["a", "b", "c"]
array1.push("d");
console.log(array1); // Array ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
console.log(array2); // Array ["a", "b", "c"]
//array2.push("e"); // throws

console.log(array2.constructor.name); // "Array"
console.log(Array.isArray(array2));   // true
console.log(array2 instanceof Array); // true
console.log(array2 instanceof ReadOnlyArray); // false
```

A proper re-usable class:

```
class ReadOnlyArray extends Array {
    constructor(mutable) {
        super(0);
        this.push(...mutable);
        Object.freeze(this);
    }
    static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array; }
}

const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const array2 = new ReadOnlyArray(array1);

console.log(array1); // Array ["a", "b", "c"]
console.log(array2); // Array ["a", "b", "c"]
array1.push("d");
console.log(array1); // Array ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
console.log(array2); // Array ["a", "b", "c"]
//array2.push("e"); // throws

console.log(array2.constructor.name); // "ReadOnlyArray"
console.log(Array.isArray(array2));   // true
console.log(array2 instanceof Array); // true
console.log(array2 instanceof ReadOnlyArray); // true
```

Comment: The cache idea is pretty nice; hadn’t thought of it for this context  Prefer it to using slice every access as some frameworks can access properties many times, e.g. in Angular JS’ digest cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Reviewing this, 2 years on, a possible solution for this is to return a copy of the array, via the property accessor. Whether it is the best approach depends on various factors (e.g. expected array size, etc.)

```
props.arr = {
   enumerable: true,
    get: function () {
        return _arr.slice();
    }
};
```

This means that calling `.push` on the array would have no affect on the original `_arr` array and the `addArrValue` method would be the only way to mutate the "private" `_arr` variable.

```
var x = new ClassName();

x.arr.push("newValue"); // Silently fails as it mutates a copy of _arr

console.log(x.arr); // []

x.addArrValue("hi");

console.log(x.arr); // ["hi"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not defineProperty, but Nowadays can use [es6 Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

not the best one imo, just an alternative, but really customizable I'd say

```
var _arr;

_arr = [];

function ClassName () {
    var props = {};

    // ... other properties ...

    this.arr = new Proxy(_arr, {
      get(obj, prop){
        console.log("prop:", prop.toString());
        if(typeof prop === "symbol"){
          return obj[prop];
        }

        // either block functions like push, pop
        switch(prop){
        // or other mutable methods
        case "push":
        case "pop":
        case "shift":
        case "unshift":
          // you can throw error
          return () => {};
        case "length":
          return obj[prop];
        }

        if(Number.isInteger(Number(prop))){ // this is not a good way, just for example
          return obj[prop];
        }

        /*
        */
        // idk which is desired
        return obj[prop]; // default behaviour just in case
      },
      set(target, key, value){
        // you can throw error
        return false;
      }
    });

    Object.seal(this);
};

ClassName.prototype.addArrValue = function addArrValue(value) {

    // ... some code here to validate `value` ...

    _arr.push(value);
}


let x = new ClassName();
console.log(x.arr);
x.addArrValue(2);
console.log(x.arr);
console.log(x.arr.toString());
console.log(x.arr instanceof Array); // true
console.log(Array.isArray(x.arr)) // true
console.log(x.arr.class); // undefined
```

Comment: you can migrate the validating process to `set()` if that was what you intended to do, as in [validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#validation)

Comment: interestingly, firefox console "knows" it (`x.arr`) is a proxy, while jsfiddle doesn't